# Horizontally align minipages from different boxes

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

I have defined the following command:

```
\newcommand{\listOfYears}[3]{

    \mbox{
        \begin{minipage}{0.08\textwidth}
        #1
        \end{minipage}

        \begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
        #2
        \end{minipage}
      }

    \mbox{
      \begin{minipage}{0.08\textwidth}
      \end{minipage}

      \begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
          \textit{#3}
      \end{minipage}
      }
}
```

I would like the third argument to be aligned with the second one(so I want `#2` and `#3` to have the same distance from the left of the page).

However, if I create an empty `minipage` before `#3` it doesn't get displayed:

```
      \begin{minipage}{0.08\textwidth}
      \end{minipage}
```

Therefore, I'm trying to use `\hphantom` but that has the same effect:

```
      \begin{minipage}{0.08\textwidth}
       \hphantom{invisible chars}
      \end{minipage}
```

So how can I create empty space before `#3`?

Comment: Please always post a complete minimal example people can compile. Much more useful than a handful or half of code fragments.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\listOfYears}[3]{%
  \begin{minipage}{0.08\textwidth}
    #1
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
    #2
  \end{minipage}
  \par
  \hspace*{.08\textwidth}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
    \textit{#3}
  \end{minipage}
}
\begin{document}

\listOfYears{765}{235}{3098}

\end{document}
```

[image: aligned minipages]